# Mac OSX How to register MSIX interrupt

Tags: macos, iokit

I am writing a PCIe Device Driver.
The hardware driver use MSIX interrupts for 4 IO command queues.
so how to register MSI-X interrupts?

I use following code for MSI interrupt.

```
ies = IOInterruptEventSource::interruptEventSource (this,
                                                             &Controller::interruptOccurred,
                                                            fProvider,
                                                            index );
```

but this code does not work for msix interrupt.

I looked over IOPCIMessagedInterruptController source, seems IOKit does support MSIX feature.
But how to add MSIX event to workloop?

Comment: Last time I tried using MSI-X (on OS X) 10.10/10.11 it didn't seem to be supported properly. I never got around to fully diagnosing it though.